# Why do we have vaccines against some diseases and not the others?

Tags: vaccination, bacteria

There's a vaccine against pneumococcus (common cause of pneumonia) but there's no vaccine against treponema pallidum (cause of syphilis).

Both are bacteria (although different kinds of bacteria).

What's the difference in layman words? Why do we have a vaccine against the former but not against the latter?